# How to skip stages in Jenkins based on capacity?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, continuous-delivery, capacity

I am trying to introduce continuous delivery in an organisation where we currently don't have enough capacity to run all tests on all commits. The below is a simplified, fictional scenario, with made up numbers, to illustrate the problem.

> [image: Continuous Delivery Pipeline]
>
> Imagine the above pipeline. We have the capacity to run the commit stage on all commits, partly because it's been designed to run fast and partly because we've mocked all the expensive parts of the environment, so that it doesn't require any expensive hardware to run. In fact, I can even run it locally on my laptop.
>
> The acceptance tests on the other hand take about 6 hours to execute and that time keeps increasing as we are introducing more features that need testing. They run against a production like environment that costs $1M a year, so we only get one of those.
>
> We have about 20 commits per day and they are normally all within office hours, so realistically, during the day, we could run the acceptance tests for the first commit, the last commit, and the commit that happened 6 hours after the first commit. There's simply no way we could run the acceptance tests on every commit.
>
> Today the commit stage is in its own job running on every commit, the acceptance tests are in another job that runs nightly, and the deployment to production is a manual process, preceded by extensive manual testing. The acceptance tests are always broken. Releases are not made from master, but from release candidate branches that goes through at least a month of testing and bug fixing before being released. We sometimes even have multiple of these ongoing at the same time, because one release didn't finish before the next scheduled release started.
>
> I desperately want to fix our broken release process, by introducing a continuous delivery pipeline. I currently don't have a solution for the lack of capacity, but skipping stages based on capacity seems like a way forward. I don't really have any doubt that this is possible to do, considering the flexibility of Jenkins, but I'm struggling to find resources on how to do it. I hardcoded the skip in the pipeline (using `when`) to generate the screenshot, so don't take that as proof that I've solved the problem.

Remember, everything in the yellow box is fiction, but the question is real:

How do I skip stages in Jenkins based on capacity?

Answer (score 0):

The way to skip stages based on capacity in Jenkins is by using a combination of `lock` and `milestone`:

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('Commit Stage') {
            steps {
                sleep 10
            }
        }
        stage('Acceptance Tests') {
            steps {
                milestone(1)
                lock(resource: "staging", inversePrecedence: true) {
                    milestone(2)
                    sleep 20
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Deploy to Production') {
            steps {
                sleep 10
            }
        }
    }
}
```

By using an `inversePrecedence` lock, the latest build will get the lock first and hence be the first one to pass milestone 2. All older builds that have already passed milestone 1 will then be aborted. By omitting milestone 1, the older builds will not be aborted until they obtain the lock, which could take forever.

Just replace the sleeps with the actual work and you will have the pipeline described in the question.

I should also mention that it is recommended to acquire the lock in a stage with `agent none`, because then the waiting jobs will not be taking up executors. It's possible to get a lock for multiple stages and each stage can execute on a different agent.

**EDIT:** After some more experimentation I realised what I did wrong. Apparently you need a `milestone` before and after acquiring the lock. Just having one after leads to the problem of builds never finishing. I figured it out after reading this blog post: https://jenkins.io/blog/2016/10/16/stage-lock-milestone/

Comment: This is a nice solution. To improve it, you could combine the lock step with a [timeout step](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#timeout-enforce-time-limit) and catch the timeout exception to not fail the build. Inside the lock step you can set some flag to enable the long test.

Comment: @DominikGebhart Actually, you're right. It is a nice solution. After some experimentation I just realised what I did wrong. I will update my answer.